# PHP mailer form data verification isn't working

Tags: php

NOTE: the mail function itself works fine, I have a hosted site with mail configured professionally. Mail is sent via this script, but my simple empty field handler never catches empty fields. I'm sure this is something super obvious, but I'm very new to php and the logic of my script seems sound. The code follows:

edit: I've left the form call within the php script in case someone finds issue with the bootstrap form itself. The redirect is temporary until I can get better form error handling going.

```
    <body>
<!-- jQuery and bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/counter.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron-fluid" id="primary">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $from = 'Web_Form_Contact';
  $to = 'example@example.com';
  $subject = 'Job_Contact';
  $c_type = $_POST["c_type"];

if (empty($_POST["c_name"])) {
    $errName = 'Info missing: Name';
  } else {
    $c_name = $_POST["c_name"];
  }

if (empty($_POST["c_email"] )) {
       $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
   } else {
     $c_email = $_POST["c_email"];
   }
if (empty($_POST["co_name"])) {
    $errCoName = 'Info missing: Company Name';
  } else {
    $co_name = $_POST["co_name"];
  }
if (empty($_POST["j_desc"])) {
    $errjDesc = 'Info missing: Job Description';
  } else {
    $j_desc = $_POST["j_desc"];
  }

  $body = "From: $c_name\n E-Mail: $c_email\n Type: $c_type\n CoName: $co_name\n Description\n $j_desc";

if (empty($errName && $errEmail && $errCoName && $errjDesc)) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch\n This page will redirect in 5 seconds.</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
} else {
  echo "$errName\n $errEmail\n  $errCoName\n $errjDesc";
    }
}
  echo "$result";
?>
<div class="container">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="php/info.php"
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10  col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
      <<h2>Contact Me! <small></small></h2>
       <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="clientEmail" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="c_email"class="form-control" id="clientEmail" placeholder="Email" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="clientName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_name" id="clientName" placeholder="Your Name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2">Contact Type</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="c_type" id="gridRadios1" value="recruiter" checked>
                I am a recruiter, and do not work directly for the company hiring.
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="c_type" id="gridRadios2" value="employee">
                I work for the company in question, and wish to discuss an open position.
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="c_type" id="gridRadios3" value="other" >
                Other
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="coName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Company Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="co_name" id="coName" placeholder="Company Name" >
          </div>
        </div>
       <!-- Job Description Text Box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Job Description ">Job Description: (1100 character max!)</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-xl-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2" >
              <div class="form-group">

                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="j_desc" id="jobDesc" placeholder="Job Description" ></textarea>
                  <p class="counter">1100</p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" id="send" name="submit" value="Send"class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--redirect script -->
<script>
function redirect(page) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = page;
    }, 5000);
}
//sends to homepage
redirect("../index.html");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an empty check for each variable:

```
if (empty($errName) && empty($errEmail) && empty($errCoName) && empty($errjDesc)) {
```

You can also set an email flag at the beginning to true, and if you hit any of the errors, you can set it to false. Then when you're ready to email, check to see if that email flag is still true.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test that out later when I get home, didn't even think about doing separate empty checks like that.

Comment: Totally solved it, thanks again! I'll keep the flag in mind for further revisions.